# PHP Array in email

Tags: php

Im trying to write a contact form and so far everything works only theres a multiple checkbox in the form and im unsure how to call all data and so my email returns 'array' for the variable 'service'

My code is...

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$to = "liam@.co.uk";

//begin of HTML message
$message = "
From : $name,
Email: $email,
Number: $number,
Service: $service,
Description: $description  
Location: $location
";
//end of message

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn";
$headers  .= "From: $email\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

My form for the service input is...

```
 <dt><input type="checkbox" value="Static guarding" name="service[]" class="cbox">Static guarding</dt>
    <dt><input type="checkbox" value="Mobile Patrols" name="service[]"class="cbox">Mobile Patrols</dt>
    <dt><input type="checkbox" value="Alarm response escorting" name="service[]"class="cbox">Alarm response escorting</dt>
    <dt><input type="checkbox" value="Alarm response/ Keyholding" name="service[]"class="cbox">Alarm response/ Keyholding</dt>
    <dt><input type="checkbox" value="Other" name="service[]"class="cbox">Other</dt>
    <dt><input type="hidden" value="Other" name="service[]"class="cbox"></dt>
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST['service']);` to view the structure of the array within the `$_POST` array. You have a multi-dimensional array here.

Comment: that returns...
array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Static guarding" [1]=> string(24) "Alarm response escorting" [2]=> string(5) "Other" } 

Im unsure how to just call the values though

Comment: Do you want them all to be listed? Check out my answer.

Comment: Yeah I need to list them all, Ill google multi dimensional arrays thanks

Comment: you have service[] as array for everything because it's set in your html form options

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [e-mail header injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_injection), since you don't sanitize `$email`.  I'd suggest using [`FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/filter.filters.sanitize) with [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/filter-input) or [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter-var) from the Filter extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can process the checkbox values into a string with [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$checkboxes = implode(',', $_POST['service']);

$message = <<<EOL
...
Service: $checkboxes

EOL;
```

Note the use of a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) - it's a MUCH nicer way of defining a multi-line string than using a regular quoted string.

Comment: Nice answer, just gonna point out you're missing a bracket in the first line and also an argument for `implode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you appended your form input names with brackets, PHP will form an indexed array out of them.

```
$sCount = count($service);
for ($s=0; $s<$sCount; $s++) {
    echo $service[$s];
}
```

You might be better off creating an associative array:

```
<dt><input type="checkbox" value="Mobile Patrols" name="service[mobile]"class="cbox">Mobile Patrols</dt>
<dt><input type="checkbox" value="Alarm response escorting" name="service[escorting]"class="cbox">Alarm response escorting</dt>
```

That way, in your script, you could access them as:

```
echo $service['mobile'];
echo $service['escorting'];
```

Note that empty checkboxes aren't submitted so you'll want to first check if the array element is set.